# How does SQL Server lookup object names in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-schema

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT user_name(); 
    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()
    SELECT * FROM MyView
END
```

I have a view named testuser.MyView. I then call the SP using:

```
exec as user = 'testuser' exec test
```

This shows the user_name and SCHEMA_NAME are both set to **testuser**
However I also get a `Invalid object name 'MyView'.` message, as the SP is still looking up the view name in the dbo schema.

Is there anyway to change how the SP is executed so the MyView object references testuser.MyView without having to use a fully qualified name?

I am trying to use a single set of many stored procedures, on identical table structures in different schemas. I really want to avoid rewriting all the SPs using dynamic SQL, or to create copies of all the SPs each using qualified names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unqualified object names are resolved using the module owner's default schema.  This behavior can't be changed so you'll need to resort to the other methods you mentioned.

Since you already create separate tables and views for each user with the same structure, why not create stored procedures in the user's schema at the same time?

Comment: Thanks Dan. I was afraid that might be the case. The SPs are pretty complicated, and there are many of them so I wanted to avoid 100s of duplicate SPs. I guess wiping and rebuilding them all with scripts for any updates is the only solution.